# Dynamic programming for longest path of a graph

Tags: python, graph, path, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to obtain a "fast" running algorithm that given an adjacency matrix of a subgraph of a transitive tournament, computes the size of a longest path, currently my code looks as follows:

```
#this function defines the adjacency matrix of a transitive tournament on n vertices

def transitive(n):
    A=np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            A[i,j]=1
    return(A)

#this one computes the adjacency matrix of a random subgraph of the graph defined above:

def Tp(A,p):
    n=A.shape[0]
    C=np.zeros(A.shape)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if A[i,j]!=0:
                if random()>p:
                    C[i,j]=0
                else:
                    C[i,j]=1
            else:
                C[i,j]=0
    return(C)
```

The algorithm i'm running is basic dynamic programming checking the longest path starting on each vertex.

This function checks the longest path starting on vertex i0

```
def long_path(B,i0):
    
    out_neighbours=np.where(B[i0,:]==1)[0]

    if out_neighbours.size==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + max([long_path(B,j) for j in list(out_neighbours)])
```

This one iterates over all vertices and obtains the size of the longest path

```
def longestpath(B,verbose=0):
    
    n=B.shape[0]
    lp=[0]*n
    
    for i in range(n):
        lp[i]=long_path(B,i)
        
        if verbose==1:
            print('For n=',n,' starting at index i0=',i,' we get a longest path of size :',lp[i])
        
    return(max(lp))
```

This algorithm in fact gives me the size of a longest path, but it takes a lot of time when iterating through the vertices, i know i could save a lot of time by running the longest path in reverse order (starting by the final vertex) and storing its size, passing over computing time to memory, but i'm not proficient enough on python to know how i would go about the proper syntax to do so.

Any help in that regard would be greatly appreciated!.

Comment: How large is your data, does it have closed loops (I guess not, don't think your code handles that case), can you post some example data?

Comment: I mean, the input data is given by the functions above, im running it on graphs of 500ish vertices, with p=log(n)/n, so few edges.

The graph is transitive, so it has no loops (its a directed graph, and all edges point towards bigger integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if this serves to anyone, i managed to do what i wanted, comitting to memory most of the work the algorithm did, and now it can compute graphs up to 10000 vertices using about the same time as it did before with 500 vertices.

```
def longestpath_fast(B):
calculated_nodes=[0]*n
for step in range(n):
    curr=n-step-1
    K=B[curr:,:]
    if curr==n-1:
        calculated_nodes[curr]=0
    else:
        out_neighbours=np.where(B[curr,:]==1)[0]

        if out_neighbours.size==0:
            calculated_nodes[curr]=0
        else:
            calculated_nodes[curr]=1+max([calculated_nodes[s] for s in out_neighbours])

return(max(calculated_nodes),np.argmax(calculated_nodes))
```

It basically computes the same thing as before, but starts from the last vertex, and saves the biggest path starting from that vertex, which is calculated as 1+ length of the longest path starting at an out-neighbour (that has to be further down the list, as this graph is transitive).